# aiogram library telegram bot with python

Tags: python

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton

# token API
bot = Bot(token='token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
#

button1 = KeyboardButton('Hello')
keyboard1 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True).add(button1)


# start command
@dp.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Vampir koylu oyununa hos geldiniz!", reply_markup=keyboard1)


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

when I tried to run the code I am getting an error that
in line 14 'Handler' object is not callable
I couldn't find the solution could you help me please ?

Comment: If you want to add a handler to `/start/ you should use the [CommandStart](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters.html#commandstart).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Start Command to (Without the s)

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
```

Comment: it is same error without s

Comment: Can you add the complete error message to the post so that I can know what to look for please?

Comment: D:\coding\python\vampiroyun\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/coding/python/vampiroyun/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\coding\python\vampiroyun\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    @dp.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
TypeError: 'Handler' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `@dp.message_handlers` the s is still there. I tried locally without s and it works fine.

Comment: D:\coding\python\vampiroyun\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/coding/python/vampiroyun/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\coding\python\vampiroyun\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    @dp.message_handlers(command=['start'])
TypeError: 'Handler' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: but without s it is same

Comment: Remove the s, **Save** the file and try again. The logs still show an s in there.

Comment: Yes, It's what I'm saying, Remove/Delete the S. `@dp.message_handlers` should become `@dp.message_handler`. It's clear you still have the s inside the code.

Comment: i understood commands going to be command , first time oky that works thank you very much